# My 3D object looks different when exporting it to Unity?

Tags: mesh, export, import, unity

I'm new to blender and Unity so my Question is simple , My Design lost some materials like some colors after Importing it to Unity , I exported it as .fbx file and Imported it to unity.

Here is The design from Blender :

[image]

and here is it after importing it to Unity and lost some colors , and looks bad not like in blender (note I didn't use textures in Blender just colors from Blender itself) :

[image]

Any help is Appreciated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sort of looks like you have a subsurf modifier on the object. Unity doesn't actually take the raw blender file when you import it as an asset. It actually exports the blender model as an fbx and then imports that into Unity. Exporters tend to apply modifiers before they export. What Unity is allowing you to do is sit back while it does all of the export/import work for you. It's also going to have some wonkiness when it comes to translating the materials so you should always use a UV texture even if you're just talking about a flat color on the object just so you have some predictability and control.

Comment: thanks for replying, so the to avoid that I shall add textures to unity and the mesh ?

I heard something about the Normals can it be the case ? 

if so how to do it please ?

Comment: You can add textures to shaders in Unity. It is true though that you should make sure your normals are correct before trying to import them into Unity.

To check the normal go into Edit mode and open the mesh properties menu by pressing 'N'. Scroll down to "Mesh Display" and go to "Normals". The buttons will display the normals and what direction they're facing. Quickest way to fix them is press 'T' for the tools panel and the "Shading/UVs" tab. Select the whole mesh and under 'Normals' click 'Recalculate'.

Comment: I tried it and It didn't work even though the materials are recognized in Unity(the colors that are not showing ) , Maybe I did something wrong ?

Thanks for your help :)